# Fire a callback only once on animating two objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was starting to make a quite complex animation with jQuery and I was looking for a certain way to animate elements together. I wrote the code somewhat as follows, which I could use to animate multiple elements together:

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wkhrU/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#firstElement, #secondElement').animate(
        {left : '+=400px'}, 
        500,
        "linear",
        function(){
            alert("completed");
        });
});
```

However, the callback function fires twice i.e. each time for the element inside. What I was looking for is to be something like animating multiple elements simaltaneously for the same time duration and after the completion, fire a call inside which I wanted to swap the `id` attrib of the elements. I can't do the same here because on completion callback, it swaps the `id`s once and on the next function callback, swaps them back again. What's the appropriate way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

You could maybe use a `promise()` to call the function to be executed instead of the inbuilt callback of `animate`. This ensures that the function in `done` is called **only** after animating both the elements. *It's basically like you're asking `#firstElement` & `#secondElement` to promise JS that it'll inform when both of 'em are done so that you could attach a `done` handler to it*.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#firstElement, #secondElement').animate({
        left: '+=400px'
    },
    500, "linear").promise().done(function () {
        alert("completed");
    });
});
```

**DEMO**

<kbd>http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/wkhrU/1/</kbd>

**MORE INFO ON USED METHODS :**

**`promise`**

- Docs : http://api.jquery.com/promise/
- What it does : Makes sure that all actions of a certain type bound to the collection, queued or not, have finished.

**`done`**

- Docs : http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/
- What it does : Add handlers to be called when the promise is resolved.

Comment: That's promising! Thanks. :)